# SED: insert something after the second last line?

Tags: sed

In a XML configuration file I need to add a line, in order to not to break the last closing tag. Is it possible to do it with SED ?

The number of line of the whole file can change from a server to another...

Edit :
Some exemple of file I need to edit :

```
<configuration>

  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <!-- encoders are assigned the type
         ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder by default -->
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <root level="debug">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```

An other exemple:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <configuration>

    <property name="DEV_HOME" value="c:/logs" />

    <appender name="FILE-AUDIT"
      class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
      <file>${DEV_HOME}/debug.log</file>
      <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <Pattern>
          %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} - %msg%n
        </Pattern>
      </encoder>

      <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <!-- rollover daily -->
        <fileNamePattern>${DEV_HOME}/archived/debug.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log
                          </fileNamePattern>
        <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy
          class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
          <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
        </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
      </rollingPolicy>

    </appender>

    <logger name="com.mkyong.web" level="debug"
      additivity="false">
      <appender-ref ref="FILE-AUDIT" />
    </logger>

    <root level="error">
      <appender-ref ref="FILE-AUDIT" />
    </root>

    <logger name="com.mkyong.ext" level="debug"
      additivity="false">
      <appender-ref ref="FILE-AUDIT" />
    </logger>

      <logger name="com.mkyong.other" level="info"
      additivity="false">
      <appender-ref ref="FILE-AUDIT" />
    </logger>

      <logger name="com.mkyong.commons" level="debug"
      additivity="false">
      <appender-ref ref="FILE-AUDIT" />
    </logger>
  </configuration>
```

Comment: To manipulate XML files you should really use XML tools such as [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/)...

Comment: @StephenKitt You're right but I need tools included with Ubuntu12 because I can't install new tools on the server.

Comment: What a mess... Could you perhaps post a _very short input sample and the expected output_ ?

Comment: Why can't you install tools on the server?

Comment: @Kusalananda it's a secured environment and each tools to be installed have to be tested and validated by a dedicated team. It's more a corporate's process problen than an inability to install it.

Comment: And yet you’re allowed to manipulate Log4J XML files directly on the server? O_O

Comment: Notice that any script that comes out of here may be considered a tool that needs to be tested and validated too. Just saying.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To <kbd>i</kbd>nsert a line before the last (`$`) one:

```
$ cat test
one
two
three
four
five

$ sed '$i<hello>!' test
one
two
three
four
<hello>!
five
```

That's for GNU `sed` (and beware leading spaces or tabs are stripped). Portably (or with GNU `sed`, if you want to preserve the leading spaces or tabs in the inserted line), you'd need:

```
sed '$i\
<hello>!' test
```

Comment: For anyone who, like me, is trying to insert a leading tab with this solution and running into problems (perhaps because I'm using sed from busybox?) the following works: `sed -e '$i \' -e $'\t'"scan_ssid=1" /tmp/connect.conf`

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `sed` can be told to act on only a specific line by writing the line number before the operation you tell it to perform. For example, to insert a line with the string `foo` after the 4th line of a file, you could do:

```
sed '4s/$/\nfoo/' file  # GNU sed and a few others
sed '4s/$/\
foo/' file # standardly/portably
```

To insert a line after the next to last line, I can think of two approaches:

1. Count the number of lines first and then make the edit:

   ```
   sed "$(( $( wc -l < file) -2 ))s/$/\nfoo/" file
   ```
2. Use `tac`:

   ```
   tac file | sed '2s/$/\nfoo/' | tac
   ```

Comment: As far as I understand I can't use the sed's -i option with `tac`?

Comment: @Fractaliste no, not with `tac`, but  you can always do `tac file | sed '2s/$/\nfoo/' | tac > newfile && mv newfile file`

Comment: You just `sed '$s/^/foo\n/'` to insert before the last one.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas yes, I know that now, after reading Kamaraj's answer, but I wasn't aware of that when I posted mine.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas yes, but this answer is still useful when one needs to refer to a line BEFORE an address (for the sake of `s` or `d` commands) since `sed` has no concept of negative offset/block. One can use analogies from this example.